# Why is Gosu hiding my mouse pointer?

Tags: ruby, graphics, mouse, libgosu

I'm doing some graphics programming using the Gosu gem. The thing is, when I create a Window my mouse pointer is hidden. I can guess where the mouse is at a certain moment, and I can intuitively click, but my users may not.

How can I show the pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using something like this:

```
class Game < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super 800, 600, false
    @cursor = Gosu::Image.new(self, 'media/cursor.png')
  end

  def draw
    @cursor.draw self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y, 0
  end
end

Game.new.show
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the same approach I settled on.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use the system cursor you can do this

```
class Window < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super 320, 240, false
  end

  def needs_cursor?
    true
  end
end
```

Check out the documentation at libgosu

[RubyGosu rdoc Reference / Window](http://www.libgosu.org/rdoc/classes/Gosu/Window.html)

Comment: Thanks, but at the time I asked this question, I think this wasn't available.